# How to scrape an Image Url in GTM to a variable?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am in need of some help in trying to scrape a product image URL which i can then capture as a variable in GTM. When using inspect console I can return the url using the following.

document.querySelector("div > div > div > img")

This returns the URL I want to capture in a variable but I cannot get it when trying to create the variable itself. Do I need a custom javascript? Can anyone help me[Image of the code im trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh5Iz.png)

Answer (score 1):

GTM has a variable type "DOM Variable", which returns a DOM element that is identified either by id or by a css selector. You can also specify which attribute of the DOM element you want to get. So you'd go to variables, news, select DOM Element as variable type, switch the selection method to css selector, enter your selector (if it matches multiple elements the variable will only return the first match) and enter "src" as the attribute whose value you want to have returned.

[image: DOM Element variable configuration]